# Android Dog App Layout

Tags: android, layout

I am creating a layout for an android dog app but I am new to android. Is there an optimised way to achieve what was shown in the image?

[image]

This is what I have done so far. I want to know how it should be laid out like the image shown. Also I want to maintain the image size on different devices like a tablet and phone. I tried scaling to XY but it doesn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.dog"
  android:background="@drawable/bg" >
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     > <!--insert progress bar-->

  </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dog"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"            
        android:src="@drawable/dog" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     > <!--insert image buttons-->

  </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: but where is the image

Comment: I don't have enough points to post it. See if you can see it here
http://imgur.com/gkbRVlU

Comment: if it is static image then u can create this image in different resolution use different `drawable folder` and place those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create that image in different resolution and place those images in `different drawable folder`.

[image]

**Screen resolution for those folder**

1. hdpi - 480 X 800
2. large-ldpi - 800 X 480
3. large-mdpi - 1024 X 600
4. mdpi - 320 X 480
5. xhdpi - 720 X 1280
6. xxhdpi - 1080 X 1920
7. xlarge-mdpi - 1280 X 800
8. large-xhdpi - 1200 X 1920 (Nexus 7)
9. xlarge-xhdpi - 2560 X 1600 (Nexus 10)